# How do I properly format FullCalendar in Angular that has Bootstrap?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar

I have Bootstrap-4 applied to my Angular project.  How do I properly activate themeSystem with Fullcalender?

I believe it is because I am not using the bootstrapPlugin properly with themeSystem.  Please let me know with my code below what I am doing wrong.

```
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap';

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public datesService: DatesService) { }

    @ViewChild('calendar', { static: false }) calendarComponent: FullCalendarComponent; // the #calendar in the template

    calendarVisible = true;
    calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin];
    calendarWeekends = true;
    calendarEvents: EventInput[] = [];
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap';

    public dates: any;


    ngOnInit() {
        this.datesService.getDates()
            .then(res => {
                this.dates = res;
                this.dates.forEach(d =>
                    this.calendarEvents = this.calendarEvents.concat({ 'title': d.projectName, 'start': new Date(d.liveDate) }))
            })
    }

}
```

The formatting on the calendar does not look like several examples online.  Please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: As per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/themeSystem the correct theme name should be "bootstrap" I believe, not "bootstrap4". Give that a try. P.S. As an aside, are you using fullCalendar's ready-made Angular component (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular)? It's not totally clear from the code. If you aren't, it's probably an easier route to go down than some custom version.

Comment: Yes.  My example was trying another option.  Still not working.  I think I can go in and directly change dist CSS.  But I do want to avoid that while doing ng builds

Comment: Hm. I'm not an Angular user so I can't advise you any further than to check you've included all the items mentioned in the bootstrap theme guide at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/bootstrap-theme, and also to try out the fullCalendar Angular component if you haven't already.

Comment: You should also import the appropriate css in your global css file.